# How to sum vector elements with the same name in R?

Tags: r, vector, sum

Most solutions I found were for data frames or lists, not for vectors.

From:
`myvec = c(A=2, B=2, A=2)`

To:
`desiredvec = c(A=4, B=2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tapply`

```
> tapply(myvec, names(myvec), sum)
A B
4 2
```

or `xtabs`

```
> xtabs(myvec~names(myvec))
names(myvec)
A B
4 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowsum` :

```
rowsum(myvec, names(myvec))
#  [,1]
#A    4
#B    2
```

`rowsum` returns a matrix. If you need a vector.

```
rowsum(myvec, names(myvec))[, 1]
#A B 
#4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Define:

```r
splitbyitsnames <- function(namedVec) { # split a list by its names
  stopif(is.null(names(namedVec)), message = "NO NAMES")
  split(namedVec, f = names(namedVec))
}

unlapply <- function (...) { unlist(lapply(...)) } # lapply, then unlist

sumBySameName <- function(namedVec) { # Sum up vector elements with the same name
  unlapply(splitbyitsnames(namedVec), sum)
}
```

From [CodeAndRoll](https://vertesy.github.io/CodeAndRoll/)

#### Call:

```r
> sumBySameName(myvec)
A B 
4 2
```

Please add if there is a better solution

---

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate/stack`

```
aggregate(values ~ ., stack(myvec), sum)
```